# My PC is randomly rebooting and it happens also during a Memory test

Tags: memtest86

I have a PC that is intermittently rebooting itself, no BSoD shown, sometimes it stops to a white screen, but mostly, it just reboots! (it's set up to Not restart on a system failure and do a memory dump).

I've taken some steps to diagnose the issue, one of them is running Memtest86 and it's rebooting when doing this test too, without time to show any errors it the Memtest86 log file.

I always have this doubt when I find this: if the memory is faulty? can it reboot the PC without logging any errors? or Memtest86 is designed in such a way that it will always log errors and the machine won't reboot if the memory is faulty?...which would point to some other hardware issue.

Any clarification much appreciated.

Comment: Since it restarts running Memtest, it seems reasonable that there is a memory error. Two things:  If more than one memory module, test them separately. Also get the manufacturer's hardware test app and test the hardware.

Comment: When memory, or any other hardware component is faulty, it’s hard to say for sure how your system will react. That’s the nature of faulty hardware. Reseat the RAM and other connections, and keep testing and/or swapping hardware until the system is stable. Typically, you’ll want to unplug ALL non-essential peripherals as well to test if it is one of those devices. This is really a standard process of elimination troubleshooting.

Comment: "*if the memory is faulty?*" -- Not necessarily. You have provided insufficient information and performed inconclusive tests.  How old is this PC?  What condition is it in?  How long from power up to a reset?  Perform a a sanity test: have the PC do nothing (e.g. let it idle in a BIOS config menu), and see if it reboots.  For a WAG I'd suspect a power issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I know those troubleshooting steps, the question I asked is other though:  I've always doubted if a memory test is designed so that the machine won't restart during testing (such as using a very small area of memory that it tests first and then tests the rest of the memory that, if faulty, is not being used, so it would always detect the faulty memory but not reboot from it, again: as it is not being used.

Comment: IMO it is unlikely for merely testing memory to cause a system reset.  This assumes that the memory test will trap any processor exceptions (e.g. trying to execute an illegal instruction) to aide troubleshooting.  A well-written memory test will periodically relocate itself in memory, in order to truly test all memory.  Or if the system has secondary memory (e.g. the SoCs I work with have 64KB of SRAM as well as the external DRAM), then such an auxiliary memory is ideal for running a program to test the main memory.  Otherwise there's a chicken versus egg quandary.

Comment: You need to test with a good memory, so it will tell if the rest of hardware is faulty or is just RAM. 
I went through this error with one module of memory, my Linux freezes a while before kernel panic, maybe the error in your machine is critical in such way that there is no room for BSOD functions, my machine has 2x2GB. memtest86 reboots in the test. I bought new memory, 2x8GB and both chips are faulty too, same error, memtest86 rebooted after trying to fill more than 25% of the announced space (i think its fake RAM).